# How to stop async method thread after timeout in JAVA

Tags: java

I have some method with render() name and I want to call it asynchronously and set timeout to that async call.

when timeout will finish I need to stop async call.
I tried such code but it doesn't stop async call after timeout

```
Future<File> fileFuture = null;
try {
        fileFuture = executor.getThreadPoolExecutor()
                    .submit(() -> render());
            return fileFuture.get(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            fileFuture.cancel(true);
            throw new MyTimeOutException(e);
        }
    }
```

How can I do this in Java?

And also It will be better that it will be done by Java java concurrent package.

And I want to add that I use Spring Boot and please write if there is any solution by Spring.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `fileFuture.cancel(true)`, Java will send an interrupt to the thread that is running `render()`. However, this by itself does not automatically stop the render task. You need to check for the interrupt from within `render()` and stop if an interrupt is detected.

Without looking at the implementation for `render()`, it's hard to say where exactly within the method you should check for it, but as a rule you should check for interrupts periodically during a long-running task. Here's an example:

```java
public void render() {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {      // some long running task
        heavyCrunch(inputs[i]);
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {                // returns true if an interrupt has been received
            // We've been interrupted: no more crunching.
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

You can read the full Oracle guide on interrupts [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)

Note that even with this solution, your `render()` method won't stop immediately when you call `cancel()` - there will be a lag between when `cancel()` is called and `render()` checks for interrupts. The more frequently you check for interrupts, the smaller this lag will be.

Comment: thank you for answer
I just need to cancel that async thread outside of that thread after timeout.
Isn't there any solution for doing it ?

Comment: You can look into `Thread.stop` and `Thread.suspend` but here's an article from Oracle on why that's a really bad idea - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html